# Survival analysis of a stratified case-cohort study in R

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, weighted-regression, case-cohort

I am trying to perform a survival analysis for a stratified case-cohort study (1:2) where cases are patients with distant recurrence (DR) and the cohort is composed by patients without distant recurrence (non-DR).
Sampling was stratified according to two variables (a = 2 levels, b = 3 levels; 6 strata in total) and therefore 12 classes combining strata and the case/cohort (DR/non-DR).
For each strata, the weight is **Wk = Nk / nk** where **Nk** is number eligible trial patients in the class and **nk** is the number successfully assessed in the class.

My question: what is the best way to perform a Cox Regression in a stratified case-cohort study?
I found an interesting package: **cchs** https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cchs/cchs.pdf but it seems that the weight is automatically computed and there is no way to enter the weight.
I've also found that in the regular coxph there is the possibility to add the weight, but it is in case of non-proportional hazard assumption.

Does anyone have some experience with this package or this type of analysis and can give me some suggestions to move on?